# How can I connect to a Windows VM, and send Win32 commands? (Python)

Tags: python, windows, linux, virtual-machine

I have a VM of Windows opened, and I'd like to able to move the cursor to a (x,y) coordinate and click, or click + sendkeys.

so 2 questions:

1) Best way to create a headless Windows VM with set resolution?]

2) How can I execute code or ideally control it with a Python API from the host(Linux) machine?

edit: I'm trying to do this because it's a complicated GUI app that is only available in Windows, and I want to control it in the background of my machine, get results, etc.

Comment: Can you just run the program inside the Virtual Machine?

Comment: Yes, I can run it. But I'd have to manually control it or make some kind of hack so all the clicks are done for me.

Comment: Crossing the VM boundary will be a neat trick. Good luck.

Comment: Couldn't you run two Python processes, one in the VM and one on the host, and have the two talk to each other over the network?

Comment: Hmm. I suppose it could. Quickly getting over my head though. :)

Comment: What virtual machine software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at http://sikuli.org/. I think it can be solution for you.

Comment: Hmm, from what I read this sikuli interacts with locahost OS. It doesn't say anything about any VM. gtY7, I have, I think the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345609/send-a-dos-command-in-a-virtual-machines-cmd-through-python-script/33345750#33345750. Maybe would help if we can exchange opinions.

Comment: Actually sikuli works on screen shots. So it works with data presented on the screen. If you have VM on the screen it will work with VM.